# OOD Java how to make 2 classes work together

Tags: java, class, object

Hi I want to make 2 classes in java, one called Students and the other called Results.
But I want the class results to be able to be accessed by other classes as well. eg I want teachers to be able to access it aswell. Im not sure how I go about doing it.

If my student class has

```
  private int id
  private String name;
  private String classname;
```

and I want my result class to read in results from a txt file eg, 1234567,C
how do I get the two of them to talk to each other aswell as allowing result to be used by other classes?Im not sure where I should declare the arraylist that will read in the results and Im not sure how to reference it to the student.
Thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: @Jixi most definitely not that.

Comment: Are `Results` a property of a `Student`, or are they independent of both `Student`s and `Teacher`s?

Comment: Im not sure what it should be?

Comment: I mean conceptually - is a `Result` a test result, for example (which means it probably should be a property of a `Student`), or is it some kind of other result?

Comment: A result is a test result, so there would be a file with multiple tests results from different students. And I want Teachers to be able to access them aswell

Comment: Do Teachers have a Result and Students have a Result, or do Teachers need to have access to a Students Result? If the Result we are talking about were a test result, A TestResult would be its own object with properties like Score, TotalCorrect, TotalIncorrect, etc. Students would have a collection of TestResult Objects representing each test they have taken. Teachers would then access a student's test result through the Student Object. (Teachers have students, Students have TestResults). I am not sure if this is the relationship you are talking about though.

Comment: Ok so there will be individual students who can only access their result. Their result will be held in a file with other results for different students. Also there will be teachers who will be able to access the results of their students aswell.

Comment: See a student will have multiple results for differen modules

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of visibility:

> `public` : All packages and their classes can use the class(by importing the package of course).
>
> `protected` : all inherited and not inherited classes in the same package can use the class.
>
> `private` : only the class and its inner methods and properties can use the class.

So just pay attention to these rules when defining your classes, properties and methods.

**I've told that they can use the class, this is true to methods and properties.**

Comment: This is a rather mysterious maxim at the end because (grammar).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need is for your `Student` class to maintain, in addition to its current `id`, `name`, and `className` properties, something like a `private HashMap<String, Results> testResults;` property that tracks their individual results on various tests for various classes (if each `Student` only takes one class, you can make this a `List<Results>` instead of a `HashMap`). This property should be accessible to the `Teacher` classes via a getter method:

```
public Results getTestResults(String className) {
    return testResults.get(className);
}
```

(Again, that's for the `HashMap` version; you won't need the `String` parameter if you're only using a `List`.)

To actually load the results into each student will require a utility class of some kind, since results for different students are stored in the same file. You'll want to maintain a collection of `Student` objects somewhere so you can look up each student by ID as you encounter it in the file, then create the `Results` object for that line, storing it in the appropriate `Student` as you go.

Hope this points you in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

in your student class write a constructor for initialisation. or write a public method to manipulation because private scopes within the class. and do inheritance you ll able access in sub class